# Spring-Hibernate Integration Framework

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, integration

I am trying to integrate the spring and hibernate.I want to save my data into database using this functionality. My files are attached as follows.

**Employee.java**

```
package springhibernate;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
    public Employee(int id, String name, float salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }


}
```

**employee.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="com.javatpoint.Employee" table="emp558">  
          <id name="id">  
          <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
          </id>  

          <property name="name"></property>  
          <property name="salary"></property>  
</class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**EmployeeDao.java**

```
package springhibernate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

public class EmployeeDao {

    HibernateTemplate template;
     public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template)
     {
         this.template = template;
     }

     //method to save employees
     public void saveEmployee(Employee e)
     {
         template.save(e);
     }

     //method to update employees

     public void updateEmployee(Employee e)
     {
         template.update(e);
     }

     //method to delete employees

     public void deleteEmployee(Employee e)
     {
         template.delete(e);
     }

     //method to return employee of given id

     public Employee getById(int id)
     {
         Employee e = (Employee)template.get(Employee.class, id);
         return e;
     }

     //method to return all employees

     public List<Employee> getEmployees()
     {
         List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
         list = template.loadAll(Employee.class);
         return list;
     }
}
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="system"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="manager"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="springhibernate.EmployeeDao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

**InsertTest.java**

```
 package springhibernate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class InsertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);
         EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");

         Employee e = new Employee();
         e.setId(114);
         e.setName("varun");
         e.setSalary(5000);

         dao.saveEmployee(e);
    }

}
```

now while running the above code i am getting the exceptions as follows. i included/ added all the jar files whatever are needed. i also saw some related questions on the stackoverflow but didn't get the proper hints.

**errors**

```
Oct 23, 2017 3:12:45 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at springhibernate.InsertTest.main(InsertTest.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/JDBCException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.JDBCException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more**
```

can anyone help me to getting out from this errors/exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `org.hibernate.JDBCException` class should be present in `hibernate.jar` or `hibernate-core.jar` depending on which version you are using. Update your question and post your dependencies along with their versions. Also make sure that those dependencies are included in your target build (war most probably). Also make sure you have no dependencies in conflict, e.g. same `jar` but with different version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure whether this solution will work just a small hunch.
Replace :

```
Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);
EmployeeDao dao = (EmployeeDao)factory.getBean("d");
```

with :

```
ApplicationContext r = new ClassPathXMLContext("applicationContext.xml);
Employee dao = r.getBean("d");
```